# Cut the GREP command in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, grep

Okay so i have a variable called search which holds the string "Find this Code - Now". I want to search for that code and if it finds it the system would reply with true or something on those lines, if it doesn't then it just exits the script with error.

I tried to use grep but i couldn't figure out how to cut only what was searched for so i could run an if else statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-q` switch and check the exit status of grep, i.e. something like `grep -q $var <file> && echo "true"`.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use grep but i couldn't figure out how to cut only what was searched for so i could run an if else statement

Grep has a switch `--only-matching`

```
 -o, --only-matching       show only the part of a line matching PATTERN
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> X="not gonna find it"
> grep -qR "$X" .; echo $?
1
> X="Find this Code - Now"
> grep -qR "$X" .; echo $?
0
```